# Rename a column if it exists in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to rename a column if it is exists

```
GO

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'MinDuration'
           AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'Category'))
BEGIN
    sp_RENAME 'Category.MinDuration', 'SingleDuration' , 'COLUMN'
END

GO
```

But getting error `Incorrect syntax near sp_RENAME. Expecting CONVERSATION, DIALOG, DISTRIBUTED or TRANSACTION`

How can I rename my column if it exists in the table?

Answer (score 15):

Try putting `exec` first:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns WHERE [name] = N'MinDuration'
           AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'Category'))
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_RENAME 'Category.MinDuration', 'SingleDuration' , 'COLUMN'
END;
```

Comment: How to check this condition on more than 1 columns, I mean if I want to check it on two/ three columns

Comment: @manusharma . . . You should ask a question describing your data and what you want to do.